# Filtering on one key value and return another

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

So, I have a dictionary like this:

```yaml
cars:
  - {type: sedan, color: "blue, red, green, yellow"}
  - {type: wagon, color: "brown, black, green, white"}
  - {type: hatchback, color: "purple, blue, orange, gray"}
```

And I want to create a new list variable that only contains the values in color when `type=wagon`. I have tried many variations of `selectattr`, `query`, `json_query`, `map`, etc., but, I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: What is your expected output exactly? The list of string `blue, red, green, yellow`, alone? A list of dictionaries? Else?

Comment: A list is ideal, I think. The scenario is that 'cars' represents an inventory, and I want to find out if we have a 'wagon' in 'blue, yellow'. With your help I've isolated the available colors, now I'm working on comparing the requested color with that list.

Comment: So, maybe an actual list like `['brown', 'black', 'green', 'white']`, is what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe add in more detail with a use case scenario like _'User A enters colours Y,Z; if any of those colours is found for wagons type of cars, then print success; else print NOK'_, or whatever your actual use case really is.

Comment: PS: in an [edit] of your question, preferable than in a comment.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but I'm doing this as a learning exercise. I was stumped on that particular point, and you guys helped me. I may be back, but for now I want to try to figure out the next steps on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary

```yaml
cars_dict: "{{ cars|items2dict(key_name='type', value_name='color') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cars_dict:
  hatchback: purple, blue, orange, gray
  sedan: blue, red, green, yellow
  wagon: brown, black, green, white
```

The usage is trivial.

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    cars:
      - {type: sedan, color: "blue, red, green, yellow"}
      - {type: wagon, color: "brown, black, green, white"}
      - {type: hatchback, color: "purple, blue, orange, gray"}
    cars_dict: "{{ cars|items2dict(key_name='type', value_name='color') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: cars_dict.wagon
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
cars_dict.wagon: brown, black, green, white
```

---

Compare a requested color with the list. Given the requests

```yaml
req:
  - {type: sedan, color: red}
  - {type: sedan, color: white}
  - {type: wagon, color: black}
  - {type: wagon, color: grey}
```

the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.color }} {{ item.type }} {{ result }}"
      loop: "{{ req }}"
      vars:
        result: "{{ (item.color in cars_dict[item.type])|
                    ternary('is available',
                            'is not available') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
msg: red sedan is available
msg: white sedan is not available
msg: black wagon is available
msg: grey wagon is not available
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand in

> I want to create a new list variable that only contains the values in color when `type=wagon`

That you want the list

```yaml
- brown, black, green, white
```

As your output.

If this is correct, then you have to filter with `selectattr`, indeed, then get the property you are interested in with a `map`.

Which gives the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: cars | selectattr('type', '==', 'wagon') | map(attribute='color')
```

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: cars | selectattr('type', '==', 'wagon') | map(attribute='color')
  vars:
    cars:
      - type: sedan
        color: blue, red, green, yellow
      - type: wagon
        color: brown, black, green, white
      - type: hatchback
        color: purple, blue, orange, gray
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  cars | selectattr('type', '==', 'wagon') | map(attribute='color'):
  - brown, black, green, white
```